# Firefox add-ons incompatible with the current version

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I loaded Firefox in the beginning, used it for a bit then had issues so I removed the program. I tried to load Firefox again, getting a newer version, and now in “Add-ons” I get an error message that I need to install ref control, which I have (and it shows up in “Add-ons” and is enabled). I also get a message that XUL Cache 1.0 isn't compatible with Firefox 8.0. So now my question: how do I fix this problem, and where do I change or update my XUL Cache 1.0 to a working program?

Comment: This question is more related to firefox. Try asking in mozilla forums http://forums.mozillazine.org/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens if add-on makers don't upgrade as fast as Firefox.

I have a round-about way:

1) download the xpi (just open in any other browser if installing from addons-dot-mozilla[-dot-com

2) open the xpi, in that there is install.rdf

3) search for tags `<em:minVersion>4.0</em:minVersion> <em:maxVersion>13.*</em:maxVersion>`

4) change the values to fit in your version.
Cheers :)

Comment: It may work , but forcefully installing incompatable addons are not good practice:)

Comment: but a good hack indeed :)